# Sharing downloaded file between steps on github actions

Tags: github-actions

I am downloading a file from AWS S3 in a github action. In the next step (same job) I am trying to edit the file. Sometimes the file is still there, and sometimes it isn't.

Each step runs a bash script, and I check at the end of the first step that the file exists. The file is being downloaded to the `$HOME` directory, so the path to the file is `/home/runner/my-file.json`

Where should I download the file to, to guarantee that it is still there on the next step?

Comment: Would it be an option to save the file as an artifact to access it on further steps, jobs or even workflows? Reference about this on the documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/advanced-guides/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to do this, I simply need to download it, edit it, then re-upload it, all within the same job. Intermittently when I come to edit it it is empty, even though the download step confirms that it is not empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just to close this off, files downloaded to `$HOME` *are* persisted between actions in the same job. I finally realised that the next step is trying to edit the file twice concurrently (I'm using some lerna scripts) and that is why it was sometimes reported as empty.

Comment: Do you have documentation for this?

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, you can't keep this file after finishing the action running, so to solve this, You should push this file to the repo where this action is currently running on, this could be done through git commands.

Thanks

Comment: It is a temporary file that I want to edit and reupload. I don't expect it to persist between jobs or after the action has run, but within steps in the same job. Surely this is possible?

Comment: Yes, it will be accessible between steps in the same job, since you downloaded it in the first step, it will be accessible through other steps, but for other jobs it won't be accessible unless you pushed it to the GitHub repo files, here it will be accessible for all jobs running.

Comment: This is my problem - intermittently the file has no contents in the subsequent step, even though the download step confirms that it is not empty.

Comment: If the problem occurs intermittently, are you sure it is related to Github Actions? Why not adding an if condition to the workflow to check if the file is empty or not, and if it is, run the workflow again?