# GitHub Actions - Where are downloaded files saved?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, github-actions

I've seen plenty of questions and docs about how to download artifacts generated in a workflow to pass between jobs. However, I've only found [one thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69627773/sharing-downloaded-file-between-steps-on-github-actions) about persisting downloaded files *between steps of the same job*, and am hoping someone can help clarify how this should work, as the answer on that thread doesn't make sense to me.

I'm building a workflow that navigates a site using Selenium and exports data manually (sadly there is no API). When running this locally, I am able to navigate the site just fine and click a button that downloads a CSV. I can then re-import that CSV for further processing (ultimately, it's getting cleaned and sent to Redshift). However, when I run this in GitHub Actions, I am unclear where the file is downloaded to, and am therefore unable to re-import it. Some things I've tried:

1. Echoing the working directory when the workflow runs, and setting up my `pandas.read_csv()` call to import the file from that directory.
2. Downloading the file and then echoing `os.listdir()` to print the contents of the working directory. When I do this, the CSV file is not listed, which makes me believe it was not saved to the working directory as expected. (which would explain why #1 doesn't work)

FWIW, the website in question does not give me the option to choose where the file downloads. When run locally, I hit the button on the site, and it automatically exports a CSV to my Downloads folder. So I'm at the mercy of wherever GitHub decides to save the file.

Last, because I feel like someone will suggest this - it is not an option for me to use read_html() to scrape the file from the page's HTML.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @mmille nope we ended up just switching to AWS Glue instead.